# Laravel Valet Installation Wrong Folders

Tags: laravel, permissions, file-permissions, laravel-valet

Whenever I install Laravel Valet (with `valet install`) it asks me for my password (which is not supposed to happen I suppose), and installs it for `root`.

Here is where things get weird. When I link a site it tells me that the link has been created, but it is never there:

```
$ valet link valet-test                                                                                                                                                                                                    
A [valet-test] symbolic link has been created in [/var/root/.valet/Sites/valet-test].
$  valet links                                                                                                                                                                                 
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 alpipego  wheel    68B Jul 20 10:12 .
drwxr-xr-x  9 alpipego  wheel   306B Jul 20 10:12 .. 
$  valet sudo ls -lah /var/root/.valet/Sites                                                                                                                                                                                       
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 alpipego  wheel    68B Jul 20 10:12 .
drwxr-xr-x  9 alpipego  wheel   306B Jul 20 10:12 ..
```

Somehow my user rights seem to be completely messed up (why does something inside `/var/root` belong to my user in the first place?).

#### Questions

- Is valet expected to ask for my password on installation?
- How can I install valet in such a manner that it places the configuration in `/Users/alpipego`?
- Any idea what might me wrong in terms of permissions?